# Interval of convergence of the power series of $f(x)=x^{0.6}$ around $a=4$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

I had to find the first four coefficients of the power series of $x^{0.6}$ at $a=4$, which i did:
$$c_{0} = 4^{3/5}$$
$$c_{1} = (3/5)4^{-2/5}$$
$$c_{2} = (3/5)(-2/5)4^{-7/5}$$
$$c_{3} = (3/5)(-2/5)(-7/5)4^{-12/5}$$

However, I need help finding the interval of convergence.

The ratio test isn't giving me the right answer. I'm also not sure whether Im representing this function as a power series correctly.

My desperate attempt was to use the binomial series $$4^{(6/10-n)}(1+x)^{6/10}$$
This is my first exposure to series and any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: the Taylor series around the point $a$ of a smooth function $f$ is defined by

$$\mathcal T(f,a):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k (x-a)^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty f^{(k)}(a)\frac{(x-a)^k}{k!}$$

where $f^{(n)}$ is the $n$-th derivative of $f$. Then you can write the desired series if you have a formula for the $n$-th derivative of $f(x):=x^\alpha$.

If we define $\alpha^{\underline k}:=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(\alpha-k)$ (these numbers are named falling factorials of $\alpha$) then we have that

$$f^{(k)}(x)=\alpha^{\underline k} x^{\alpha-k}$$

Thus the coefficients of your Taylor series, for $f(x):=x^{3/5}$ and $a:=4$, are defined by

$$c_k:=\frac{(3/5)^\underline k 4^{3/5-k}}{k!}$$

Then you only need to apply here your knowledge about how to obtain the [radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) of $\mathcal T(x^{3/5},4)$, what you named as interval of convergence.

> HINT 2: if the following limit exists then the radius of convergence is defined by $$R:=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{|c_k|}{|c_{k+1}|}$$

Comment: thank you for responding.Evaluating c_k/c_k+2 , i get 20/3(k+1) so the limit is divergent, is this correct? I've never heard of the falling factorials before, so Im not 100% sure im doing this right.

Comment: I have that $$\begin{align}\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{|c_k|}{|c_{k+1}|}&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{|(3/5)^\underline k| 4^{3/5-k}(k+1)!}{|(3/5)^\underline{k+1}| 4^{3/5-k-1}k!}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{4(k+1)}{|3/5-k|}\\&=4\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{k-3/5+8/5}{k-3/5}=4\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{8/5}{k-3/5}\right)=4\end{align}$$

Comment: wouldn't you also include $$(x-4)^k/(x-4)^{(k+1)}$$ with what you did up there, so it would be $$4/(x-4)$$ then i can evaluate : $$|x-4|/4<1 = x<8$$ right?

Comment: the definition of the radius of convergence doesnt need to take in account $(x-a)^k$ because the radius of convergence defines the values around $a$ where the power series converges, that is, the series converges if $|x-a|<R$, what is equivalent to say that the Taylor series $\mathcal T(x^{3/5},4)$ represent the function $x^{3/5}$ when $x\in(0,8)$, or as you had seen $0<x<8$

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your help!